# Unable to run php

Tags: php, localhost

i am unable to run my php script using the following command :
http://localhost/test.php

after typing the above command am getting a dialog box to open or save file named as test.php
m unable to get through the error.please help !

Comment: OS is ubuntu 9.04, apache server ,php5 is the version i installed .

Comment: You have to install php first :p

Comment: Nowadays we use [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for quickest PHP setup on your localhost, might as well check this [windows php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUwRinHHTCo) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed PHP properly. Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have mod_php installed? This looks like, that the Apache couldn't interpret the PHP script.

If you are on windows I would recommend: [Apache Friends](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html)

Comment: what is mod_php ? It might be the case .m really not sure .

Comment: did you tried the first four commands from: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/installing-php5-and-apache-on-ubuntu/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use xampp or wamp server instead, if you are trying to develop some applicaiton quickly, else follow the instructions from here [php Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php)